# Python: Differences between the += operator and append

Tags: python, list, append

I was just trying out some things in the interpreter and I noticed some difference between the following operations on lists, and I was wondering if anyone could explain why the output is different. Any help is much appreciated!

Suppose I create two lists a and b (and I always begin with this chunk of code before each of the following 3 cases):

```
>>> a=[1,2]
>>> b=[3]
>>> a.append(b)
>>> a
[1, 2, [3]]
```

When I append/add another element into the list b, sometimes it is reflected in the list a and sometimes it doesn't, depending on which operation I use (shown below):

Case 1: Use of += operator

```
>>> b+=[5]
>>> a
[1, 2, [3, 5]]
```

Case 2: Use of = operator

```
>>> b=b+[5]    
>>> a
[1, 2, [3]]
```

Case 3: Use of append:

```
>>> b.append(5)
>>> a
[1, 2, [3, 5]]
```

Could someone explain why the value of a is sometimes not updated to reflect the new value of b depending on which operator you use? It's kind of confusing especially as I have always assumed that b+=x does the same thing as b= b+x. It would be great if someone could point me in the direction of some documentation for the different operations (from what I've read so far I only understand what the operators are supposed to do and not how they do it, which I suspect is what is causing the difference...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b=b+[5]` creates a new list object and assigns it to name b. but the list a still refers the original list.

`b+=[5]` which is called `augmented assignment` internally calls an extend function and much more faster then concatenation. This does't create a new list but makes in-memory change similar to append call on the list.